# How to pass in a value of a prop defined using the "this | that | other thing" syntax?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have the following mapper function in which I'm trying to specify an value in a JSX prop, but the type definition won't allow me to pass in the value. Below is the code ...

```
function mapper(notification: NotificationMessageType) {
  let style = "info";

  switch (notification.icon) {
    case NotificationIconEnum.Error:
      style = "error";
      break;

    case NotificationIconEnum.Warning:
      style = "warning";
      break;
  }

  return (
    <Notification
      key={notification.id}
      type={{ style: style }}
      closable={true}
      onClose={() => notificationContext.close(notification.id)}>
      <span>{notification.message}</span>
    </Notification>
  );
}
```

The prop that is complaining is the `type` prop of the `Notification` component at the bottom of the snippet. The `type` prop is defined as ...

```
type?: {
  style?: 'none' | 'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'info';
  icon?: boolean;
};
```

But me passing in a `string` there causes TypeScript to say it's not a compatible type.

Since I can't import that type definition from `Notification`, how do I pass in the value?

Edit:

By the way, the error message says ...

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"info" | "error" | "warning"
> | "none" | "success"'.ts(2322) Notification.d.ts(57, 9): The expected
> type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type '{
> style?: "info" | "error" | "warning" | "none" | "success"; icon?:
> boolean; }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could define the `style` variable as having that type:

```
let style: 'error' | 'warning' | 'info' = 'info';
```

It'd be cleaner to put this into a function, and avoid the `switch` as a bonus:

```
const getStyle = (icon: NotificationIconEnum) => {
  if (icon === NotificationIconEnum.Error) return 'error';
  if (icon === NotificationIconEnum.Warning) return 'warning';
  return 'info';
};
function mapper(notification: NotificationMessageType) {
  return (
    <Notification
      key={notification.id}
      type={{ style: getStyle(notification.icon) }}
      closable={true}
      onClose={() => notificationContext.close(notification.id)}>
      <span>{notification.message}</span>
    </Notification>
  );
}
```

This way TS can infer the proper desired type automatically without extra type noise.

Comment: Ah you're right. That seems to satisfy TS. Thanks